# MySQL filter two field in recordset error on Update - VBA Excel - Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'

Tags: mysql, vba, filter

I have a MySQL database from which I request a recordset of clients, and then I filter the recordset for a specific client based on two fields: 1) client code and 2) year applicable. I then assign values from a userform's objects to the MySQL fields, and update that specific client's records to the database.

I get the following error upon updating the table (running 'rstIT.Update'), and I think it has to do with the way I am implementing the filter:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w)
> Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.2.36-MariaDB-log-cll-lve]Build WHERE ->
> insert_fields() failed

I am sure there must be an easier / more clever way to filter for the correct client, and update the records accordingly. Any help to resolve my current problem or another method would be greatly apppreciated!

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstIT As ADODB.recordSet
Dim rstClients As ADODB.recordSet

Dim Jaar As String

Jaar = cboTaxPeriod.Text
ITID = lblClientCode.Caption

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim str As String

str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=myserveraddress;DATABASE=mydatabasename;PORT=myport;UID=user_"
str = str & LCase(LoggedInName)
str = str & ";PWD="
str = str & Password
str = str & ";FOUND_ROWS=1;"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = str
cn.Open
Set rstIT = New ADODB.recordSet

With rstIT
    .Open "IT", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
End With

    rstIT.Filter = "ClientCode = '" & ITID & "' AND TaxYear = '" & Jaar & "'"

        If rstIT.EOF Then
            MsgBox "Client code does not exist in tax table.", vbOKOnly, "Choose new client code"
            GoTo GaanUit 'This closes everything and exits
        Else
            rstIT!TaxStatus.value = LTrim(RTrim(cboTaxStatus.Text))
            rstIT!TaxStatusStaff.value = RTrim(LTrim(lblTaxStatusStaff.Caption))
            
            If lblDueDate.Caption <> "" Then
                lblDueDate.Caption = Format(lblDueDate.Caption, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                rstIT!DueDate.value = lblDueDate.Caption
            Else
                rstIT!DueDate = Empty
            End If
                        
        End If

rstIT.Update
```

Comment: you have a mariadb and use a mysql 8 driver, did you try the mariadb driver instead?

Comment: nbk - I will take a look at the MariaDB driver. The database is MySQL as far as I know. I'm not familiar with MariaDB.

Comment: your erro rmessage says 5.5.5-10.2.36-MariaD  this is still old a s we have now 10.4 and abouve

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that *code* and *year* are numeric, thus no quotes:

```
rstIT.Filter = "ClientCode = " & ITID & " AND TaxYear = " & Jaar & ""
```

Comment: At the moment both fields are string. Year should actually be numeric, but string was used for testing purposes. Should not have an influence on how the filter are working though for updating the records.